# Changing orientation on Turtle Graphics function

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've created a function to draw my panda face 6 times, facing different directions (North, North East, East etc.) The function has 3 parameters, x and y location and .setheading. When I change the setheading it mucks up the rest of the drawings. Just wondering If I'm missing or doing something obvious  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaRsH.png)

Here is my code:

```py
import turtle

def draw_panda(x, y, direction):
    # Set the direction of the bunny
    turtle.setheading(direction)

    # Draw first ear
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x - 24, y + 95)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(11)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw second ear
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x + 24, y + 95)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(11)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw head
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y + 35)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('white')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(35)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw first eye
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x - 18, y + 75)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(8)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw second eye
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x + 18, y + 75)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(8)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw first colored eye
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x - 18, y + 77)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('blue')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(4)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw second colored eye
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x + 18, y + 77)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('yellow')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(4)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw nose
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y + 55)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('black')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(5)
    turtle.end_fill()

    # Draw mouth
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y + 55)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(5, 180)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y + 55)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.left(360)
    turtle.circle(5, -180)

# Draw six bunnies facing different directions
turtle.speed('fastest')

draw_panda(0, 0, 0)
draw_panda(100, 0, 45)
draw_panda(200, 0, 90)
draw_panda(0, -100, 135)
draw_panda(100, -100, 180)
draw_panda(200, -100, 225)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: `setpos` isn't relative and doesn't respect the turtle's current heading or current position. Try drawing everything relative to the current heading and position with `forward()`, `left()`, `right()` and the rotations will occur naturally.

Comment: So I keep the .setheading parameter in my function but change setpos ? And replace setpos with forward, left, right?

Comment: Pretty much. The idea is to avoid using any sort of `set` call at any point when drawing because it's never relative and doesn't take into account that the turtle is totally rotated. You can use `set` initially or when switching from one drawing to the next though.

Comment: Can I still use setpos and setheading in my function? Otherwise I'm not sure how to call the drawing in different areas and directions. Sorry I'm in my first month of coding still trying to learn the basics

Comment: No problem, sorry for not being clear. There are two parts to the logic: the first is determining what the initial position and rotation will be for a panda face. The second is actually drawing the panda face. In the first part of the logic, when you're setting up where the panda face should go and the rotation of the whole face, you may use `setpos` and `setheading`. In the second step, however, when you're drawing the face, you should avoid these methods. The reason is that they are absolute and don't take the current turtle rotation or position into account. Make all drawing steps relative.

Comment: Awesome I get it now. Thank you so much you've been a big help!

Comment: NP. If you arrive at a solution feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).